# How to get Grafana CloudWatch Cross-account / Cross-Region Metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

I have 4 AWS accounts (DTAP) and I want to be able to create one dashboard in Grafana with the cost per service (for all accounts).

So far I can easily create one dashboard in Dev with the costs for all services (using this dashboard: https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/139)

I also enabled cross account cross region in AWS (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Cross-Account-Cross-Region.html) which works nice (in AWS CloudWatch).

Now the problem which I am having is that I can't specify an account selector in this Grafana dashboad 139, or modify the query in such way that I can get metric from different account than Dev:

`REMOVE_EMPTY(SEARCH('Namespace="AWS/Billing" MetricName="EstimatedCharges"', 'Average', 3600))`

Does anyone has any idea how to get this or which fields are the ones for account select in AWS? I need a programatic way of running "View data for" from the picture below and graph it in Grafana:

[image]

Also, I want to avoid creating multiple data sources for each account (due to other limitations)

Comment: were you ever able to get this working @Zatarra ? i'm trying to figure out the same thing now